# in 18.04 how do I get the "windows network" to open up

Tags: networking

I installed 18.04.  Beautiful.  In the "files" I select "other" and it does show the "windows network" (my other computer is win7 which was networked with this as an XP system).
But if I select the "windows network" it tries to open it and then says it is an "empty folder".
To me, that means it is not connecting in some way.  How can I get it to access the win7?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have samba 4 installed in the package manager. Then in the file browser, supposing the win7 name is mypc with ip address 192.168.0.2 (you can find the IPs using ipconfig on windows's cmd), try something like smb://mypc/ or smb://192.168.0.2/

You may also need to check if the windows 7 firewall isn't blocking the access

If windows asks for login, it should be the same login you use to log in the windows sessions. You might have trouble connecting from the network if you don't have a password set. You can tell linux to use some specific username using an url like this:
smb://username@mypc/

For windows to access the samba sharing you may need to tweak the file /etc/samba/smb.conf using root. Microsoft changed sharing defaults so depending on which windows updates you got in Windows 7 you may also need to add the foolowing setting in the smb.conf:

```
[global]
protocol = SMB3
```

Comment: This was great.  Adding Samba to both Ubuntu computers made them all visible in the "network".  The win7 lists both Ubuntus and both Ubuntus list the "Windows Network".   When I select win7 computer on the network from the Ubuntu PCs I get the message that it is unable to access that location.  I have NordVPN on the win7 and you have to add a TAP server (?) I noticed that ipconfig no longer gives information but says it's disconnected.

Comment: I went to "files" and added "sharing" to my "download" file.  Now It is visible on the win7.  It requires me to log in and I can't figure what login it wants.  I tried the login from the Ubuntu computer and then login on the Win7 PC, but neither work.  Having all computers show up in "network" and then listing the shared directories is 2/3 the way there.

Comment: I update the answer with some additional hints you can try

Comment: @PSimdars As you're new on this site, please don't edit your question to include `[Solved]` but instead don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of  [the answer that is the most useful of all](/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: @user66395: *Excellent first answer!*  **+1  ;-)**